# Effective Resistance of two joined Vertices

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, random-graphs, network

Let $G=(E,V)$ be a connected Graph with $V \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$
Am I right with my assumption that if $(x,y) \in E$ meaning x and y are connected with an edge $e$ with the conductance $c(e)$.
Then the effective resistance between those two points is at most $R(x \leftrightarrow y) \leq \frac{1}{c(e)}$ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by $(x,y)\in G$. Is it an edge from vertex $x$ to vertex $y$?

Comment: Yes I mean the that the two vertices are connected by an edge in the Graph G

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is correct, as adding any edges to any graph cannot increase the effective resistance between any two vertices.

Comment: That is Rayleigh's Monotonicity Law thank you very much

Comment: Ah, that was the name. Glad this helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the things that's quick to see from the random-walk definition of effective resistance. (Knowing the monotonicity law is also quick, of course, but less generally useful.)

In that interpretation, we define $R(x \leftrightarrow y)$ in terms of the probability that the conductance-weighted random walk starting at $x$ reaches $y$ before it returns to $x$. If that probability is $p$, and if $c_x$ is the sum of the conductances of all the edges incident to $x$, then $$R(x \leftrightarrow y) := \frac{1}{p \cdot c_x}.$$

Well, if there is an edge $e$ from $x$ to $y$, there is a probability of $\frac{c(e)}{c_x}$ that the conductance-weighted random walk goes directly from $x$ to $y$. If that happens, then it definitely reaches $y$ before returning to $x$. So we have $$p \ge \frac{c(e)}{c_x}$$
which tells us that $p \cdot c_x \ge c(e)$, and therefore $R(x \leftrightarrow y) \le \frac1{c(e)}.$